# Тип даных даты в T-SQL.

Tags: sql

Мне нужно использовать день и месяц (отправление рейса) но без года, какой тип даных посоветуете использовать? В Datetime Можна для всех ставить однинаковый год но мне не нравится такой вариант.

Comment: Насколько я знаю в MS SQL Server типы данных для работы с датами всегда будут включать год. Т.е. вам придется либо хранить данные (день и месяц)в строке, а затем производить необходимые операции над ними(парсить/сплитить или приводить к типу данных datetime с одинаковым годом, что вас не устраивает) либо просто сделать два столбца - один под день, другой под месяц.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно хранить дату и выбирать из нее day(date), month(date)